# Performance tile showing different records for same method

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

Currently in Performance tile in Insight we have performance detail for the application request.

If we have an API like:

```
GET /order/{orderId}
```

so, for this kind of request, it showing as different request and matrix is also different for different orderId.

But for the owner point of view, this is a same request and needs to have shown under one request for all call for this method.

For the above mentioned API, if we have the request coming as:-

/order/1

/order/2

/order/3

Then in Azure portal, under performance tile for Application insight, it consider this as different operations and hence show stats individually for each unique request.
But as per the developer, this is a single API and needs to monitor as single operation.

How to achieve this in Azure portal?

[image]

Comment: It'd be helpful if you explain the issue with some screenshot as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the Performance tab, you have the ability to add filters for your results but in your scenario I would:

- Click on **View in Logs (Analytics)**
- Select **Requests**
- Add an appropriate contains statement: `| where operation_Name contains "GET /order"`

At this point the Overall line contains the total Duration Average and Count shown in the Performance tab, as well as percentile information for all orders.

[image: Navigating to View in Logs (Analytics)]

[image: Consolidated information shown]